# Reset timer on button press and start from 0

Tags: swift

I have this code:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

It runs after 3 seconds the update function. But how can i reset the timer? Evertytime that the user pushed a button the timer must be resetted and count from 0 to 3. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a same new `NSTimer` and invalidate the old one.